# FFmpeg use AAC encoder

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to do some video conversion with FFmpeg. I have an mp4 video file (by which I mean, "it has an mp4 extension") that isn't being accepted by the Brasero disk burner, so I'm trying to use FFmpeg to convert it to a file that is actually mp4.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
ffmpeg -i 5.mp4 Parkford-05.mp4
```

It tells me that the AAC encoder is experimental and I should add `-strict -2` to use it. So I try:

```
ffmpeg -i 5.mp4 Parkford-05.mp4 -strict -2
```

and get the same result.

How do I tell it to use the experimental encoder?

Comment: It is possible that you may not need to perform any re-encoding. Please show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i 5.mp4`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for:

```
ffmpeg -i 5.mp4  -strict -2 Parkford-05.mp4
```

or

```
ffmpeg -i 5.mp4  -strict experimental Parkford-05.mp4
```

[trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC)

also

[trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#NativeFFmpegAACencoder](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#NativeFFmpegAACencoder)

---

Additionally, if the file is named "5.mp4" but is not actually an mp4 file, the use of the mp4 extension in the name can cause problems. However, it is not always necessary to provide a file extension; having no file extension does not usually cause problems.

Try renaming the file "5" instead of "5.mp4" and see if that doesn't help.

Comment: Why do you answer with an `avconv` example? `avconv` != `ffmpeg` (although in this case it probably would not be too much different). Also, I'm guessing `avconv` will ignore `-qscale` if libx264 is being used as the encoder, or at least `ffmpeg` will; I'm not a user of `avconv` so you will have to check.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I have added the ffmpeg equivalent in case you absolutely need to or want to use ffmpeg or have maybe installed ffmpeg through some third party.

Comment: The deprecated message refers to the fake, now dead "`ffmpeg`" from Libav, not `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg. Unfortunately the message did not make any distinction causing many users to assume it referred to `ffmpeg` from FFmpeg (some assume this was intentional). The package maintainer refused to clarify the message to be less confusing in that aspect although I requested a change, but this was unsurprising since he is also a Libav dev. FFmpeg returned to Ubuntu in 15.04.

Comment: As for `-qscale` with no stream specifier, using it with a non-ancient `ffmpeg` build will result in various messages: `Please use -q:a or -q:v, -qscale is ambiguous` and `[libx264] -qscale is ignored, -crf is recommended`. For `aac` it is ignored as well. This can be confirmed by using the [md5 muxer](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#md5-1).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard yeah i was referring to using qscale with avconv and assumed -q:a or q:v would be used with ffmpeg as stated in the link I provided https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AAC#NativeFFmpegAACencoder

Comment: The encoder 'aac' is experimental but experimental codecs are not enabled, add '-strict -2' if you want to use it.